# Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, string, textbox, full-text-search

So I have a textbox which allows a max entry of 5 characters.

The user should enter the time in the format hh:mm or hhmm , into the textbox.

Supposing the user enters 1:2:3 or 1::2 etc, then it should show an alert message('Incorrect time format')

Is there any way I can check all other occurences of : EXCEPT for the first : , and alert the user?

(This needs to be done within a javascript function)

This is what I used to check for non-digit values(excluding :) entered into textbox:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>

    function getClks(){
    ...
    var re=":";
    var found = clks.match(re);
     if (clks.match(/^[0-9:]/)){
    alert('Invalid time value');
    }

    if (found=:){
    var splitime = clks.split(":");
    var hours = splitime[0];
    var mins = splitime[1];
......
    }
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a very good reason to *change* the user's input. I would recommend only alerting the user that their input doesn't match the correct format.

If you really want to remove characters, you can use the [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function with some regex to remove the extra `:` chars.

You can use [`search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) or [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to test whether the input is in the correct format.

Something like `/^\d{1,2}:\d{2}$/` should work.

Comment: You forgot `RegExp.prototype.test`

Comment: @Raynos, yes I did, I also didn't check that the time is valid. I probably should have used /^(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})$/ and then added some functionality to check that `$1 < 24` and `$2 < 60`.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this jquery plugin: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/
It will mask your textbox:

```
$("#hour").mask("99:99");
```

Comment: Thanks alex :) but unfortunately, I can't use jQuery in my code. Is there any string method which can help me achieve it?

Comment: -1 Use jQuery dependancy and a plugin for jQuery on top of that? Horrid.

Answer (score 0):

@alexl's jQuery plugin is probably enough, but for completeness sake..

Outside jQuery contexts I'd use a  [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp), `/([0-9][0-9]):([0-9][0-9])/`, and test the number string like so:

```
var timestr = /* .. get the text .. */
if(timestr.match(/([0-9][0-9]):([0-9][0-9])/) {
    console.log('Good number string');
} else {
    console.log('Bad number string');
}
```

Comment: The jQuery plugin is complete overkill and ridiculious to use.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone else explained what to do. Here's a more concrete example of how to use it.

```
var regex = new RegExp("\\d{2}[:]\\d{2}");

if (regex.test(input)) {
   var array = input.split(":");
   var hours = array[0];
   var minutes = array[1];
} else {
   alert("malformed input");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

markup

```
<input id="myinput" maxlength="5" type="text" />
<input type="button" onclick="test()" value="test" id="testbtn" />
```

js

```
    var re = new RegExp("^([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3])(:([0-5][0-9])){1,2}$");
    var myInput = document.getElementById('myinput');
    function test(){
        alert(re.test(myInput.value)); //alerts true if the input is well-formed
    }
```

example => http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/rRZLx/

Comment: Thanks..but could you explain what this does?            var re = new RegExp("^([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3])(:([0-5][0-9])){1,2}$");
                                                                   I'm not that familiar with regex, thats why.

Comment: ([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]) => 2 digits between 00 and 23 (i.e. 24 is NOT ok) ... : => after two digits, a colon MUST be present... ([0-5][0-9]) => 2 digits between 00 and 59 (i.e. 60 is NOT ok)

Comment: And.. most important.. ^ => regexp starts, $ => regexp ends

Comment: ok. I think I'm able to understand it a little. But I have a 12 hour format in my code, so how do I write it for that? Also, I'm doing a separate validation for users entering in hhmm format as well..so in my code,colon is not a must, unfortunately. Which is why, I just want to be able to count the no. of colons and if its greater than 1 , then show the alert. Any suggestions?

Comment: `/(?:0?\d|1[012]):?[0-5][0-9]/` Should probably work for you, as long as you don't care about seconds. It'll match 12:00 as well as 0:00, not sure how picky you are about the values.